# How to convert a map to individual columns in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with values like below and I am struggling to find ways to convert  in the input dataframe to separate columns like Id, Fld1, Fld2. Appreciate any help or pointer to the documentation which does this ?

```scala
val df2  = Seq(
  ("1", Map("Fld1" -> "USA","Fld2" -> "UK")),
  ("2", Map("Fld1" -> "Germany", "Fld2" -> "Portugal"))
).toDF("id", "map")
df2.show()
```

Input:

```
+---+-----------------------------------+
|id |map | 
+---+-----------------------------------+
|1  |[Fld1 -> USA, Fld2 -> UK]          | 
|2  |[Fld1 -> Germany, Fld2 -> Portugal]|
+---+-----------------------------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+---+-------+--------+ 
| id| Fld1  | Fld2   | 
+---+-------+--------+
| 1 | USA   | UK     |
| 2 |Germany|Portugal|
+---+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the performant solution:

```scala
df2
  .withColumn("Fld1", $"map".getItem("Fld1"))
  .withColumn("Fld2", $"map".getItem("Fld2"))
  .drop("map")
  .show()
```

```
+---+-------+--------+
| id|   Fld1|    Fld2|
+---+-------+--------+
|  1|    USA|      UK|
|  2|Germany|Portugal|
+---+-------+--------+
```

The other answer suggests using `pivot` which can be really slow.

Answer (score -1):

You could `explode` the map using the `selectExpr` and then apply `pivot` as shown below:

```scala
.selectExpr("id", "explode(map)")
.groupBy(col("id")).pivot(col("key")).agg(first(col("value")))

// result
+---+-------+--------+
|id |Fld1   |Fld2    |
+---+-------+--------+
|1  |USA    |UK      |
|2  |Germany|Portugal|
+---+-------+--------+
```